# need Iptables example for UDP

Tags: centos, iptables, openvpn

I setup openvpn at Centos vps. It has venet0 and tun0 nic. I try to open 5060 udp port for my vpn client pfsene, it shows udp port open or filter. Is these right iptables rules?

```
iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.8.0.2 -i venet0 -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d "vps public ip" -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0 -o venet0 -j SNAT --to-source "vps public ip"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply configure `iptables` rules using `firewall-cmd` utility.

For example:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5060/udp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: I setup openvpn at openVZ vps. Does it support masquerade?

Comment: If vps supports iptables NAT module, then MASQUERADE would be supported too